# How to upload the map legend in the web map closed rather than open when opening the web page?

Tags: javascript, legend, arcgis-js-api

I have a map legend through the ESRI Api. When I open the page it comes off as open [image]

How would I make it so that when i open the page it comes off as closed like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
const layerList = new LayerList({
          view: this.mapView,
          style: 'card',
          container: document.createElement('div'),
          listItemCreatedFunction: function(event: any) {
            setTimeout(function() {
              const item = event.item;
 item.panel = {
                  content: 'legend',
                  open: false
                };
             });
          }
        });
```

Reference : [esri-widgets-LayerList](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-LayerList.html)